# Using bare words to declare a JavaScript object manually

Tags: javascript, json, bareword

I'm a beginner to JavaScript and am trying to refactor an API, but I'm running into a strange problem.

I use the `node` interpreter to test some of the code I'd like to incorporate in my redesign, but I've run into some unexpected behavior.

Consider the following entered into the node interpreter:

```
[In0] b
```

I expect a ReferenceError, which I get as seen below.

```
[Out0] 
ReferenceError: b is not defined
at repl:1:1
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
at bound (domain.js:254:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

Next

```
 [In1] 'b'
 [Out1] 'b' // this is OK because it's a string
```

Now consider a JSON-style object:

```
 [In2] var x = { 'b' : 'c' };
 [Out2] { b : 'c' }
```

Strangely enough, the quotes are dropped on the key of `x`. I'm willing to overlook this, though it is confusing.

Finally,

```
 [In3] var y = { b : 'c' };
 [Out3] { b : 'c' }
```

Without the quotes, the interpreter does not complain and yields the same results as with quotes.

I also noticed that this pattern, `key` is *always* returned as a string:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    key;
 }
```

Noticing this behavior, I tried to write a method, `Bar` within my class `Foo`, as defined as follows:

```
function Foo(a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.Bar = function(attr, val) {
        // attr doesn't need to be a string to be a key in object x
        var x = { attr : val };
        for(var key in x) {
            //key DOES need to be a string to be used like this
            this[key] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially `Bar` just adds the key-value pair of `attr:val` to an object of type `Foo`.

I attempted to test this code with the following:

```
[In4] var foo = new Foo('c');
[Out4] { a : 'c', Bar : [Function] } // this is OK. I expect this.

[In5] foo.Bar(hello, "World");
[Out5]
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
at repl:1:9
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
at bound (domain.js:254:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

Can anyone explain this behavior to a noob? It's very frustrating to not be able to use a bare word as a key within a method when it can be done manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context matters a lot in language parsing.

In JavaScript, property names are always either strings or `Symbol`s (that last is new in ES6). In an [object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer), you can specify a property name without quotes (using a literal name, which must be an [*IdentifierName*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-identifier-names)), as a numeric literal (which is converted to a string), or as a string literal (e.g., with quotes):

```
var a = { b: 'c' };
// is the same as
var a = { 'b': 'c' };
// is the same as
var a = { "b": 'c' };
```

*(In ES6, you can also use computed property names in square brackets, but that's not relevant here, and in any case they end up being either `Symbol`s or strings after being computed.)*

So in an object initializer, the *context* tells the parser that it's expecting a property name, for which either literal or string notation is allowed. But here:

```
foo.Bar(hello, "World");
```

...the context tells it that `hello` is an *identifier*, because the grammar says that the individual argument values (contents of the parentheses) in a function call are expressions, and a single word on its own in an expression indicates an identifier. Since it's an identifier you haven't declared, you get a `ReferenceError`.

> Strangely enough, the quotes are dropped on the key of x. I'm willing to overlook this, though it is confusing

That's the standard notation for showing an object's properties, when the property name is a valid *IdentifierName*.

---

Re your comments:

> > I'm a beginner to JavaScript and am trying to refactor an API
>
> Fair enough. It looks like there's no better way than to force the user to pass strings.

Right, the correct way to pass around property names is as strings, sometimes numbers (as with array indexes), or `Symbol`s, which you then use to access the properties using "brackets" notation:

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
var name = "foo";
console.log(foo[name]); // "bar"
```

(When you do that with a number, it's coerced to a string. And yes, that happens [in theory] when you use array indexes with JavaScript's standard arrays, because [they aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).)

That doesn't mean that the users of your API should be required to type string *literals* though. If there's a set of allowed property names, you can make those available as properties on an object.

```
var API = {
    Things: {
        Foo: "Foo",
        Bar: "Bar"
    }
};
```

...then using the API:

```
someApiMethod(API.Things.Foo);
```

You can even define those read-only to prevent accidental overwriting:

```
var API = {Things: {}};
["Foo", "Bar"].forEach(function(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(API.Things, name, {
        enumerable: true, // Or not, whichever
        value: name
    });
});
```

By default, properties defined with `defineProperty` are read-only.

In ES6, they can also be *constants*:

```
const Foo = "Foo";
const Bar = "Bar";
```

Comment: I know there's a difference between a 'JS object' and the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), but the latter demands the key to be a string. I suppose this is what I thought was strange.

Comment: @erip: Yup, that's one of the things that Crockford did to simplify JSON parsing, just like strings can be either quoted by `'` or `"` in JavaScript, but must be quoted by `"` in JSON.

Comment: Fair enough. It looks like there's no better way than to force the user to pass strings. Thank you!

Comment: @erip: I don't follow you. What user, and what do you mean "force"?

Comment: `I'm a beginner to JavaScript and am trying to refactor an API`

Comment: @erip: Right, that's the correct way to pass around property names (as strings, numbers, or `Symbol`s). That doesn't mean the users of the API have to type string *literals*, though; I've added to the answer to explain further.

Answer (score 0):

`hello` is expected to be an expression here, e.g., a reference.

It isn't, hence the failure.

It's syntactic sugar that allows the form `{ foo: 'bar'}`. The interpreter knows that you're inside an object declaration and pretends it's a string.

(JS doesn't have symbols. Until ES6, which I neglected to mention.)

Comment: At what point is `hello` expected to be an expression? As it's passed to the method or as it's used as a key in `x`? If it's the former, that's annoying. If it's the latter, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @erip If you're not in an object declaration it will always be an expression (a reference). I'm not sure I'm understanding your objection clearly. There's a really simple rule: if you're in an object declaration, and declaring the key, it'll be treated as a string. Anywhere else, not that.